# np.polyfit won't plot a characteristic but gives values

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

The issue I am having is that when I use the code below to find the norm-1 of my error. Firstly, when I plot the error against step-size h, the error values are quite small, in the range of 10^-14 to 10^-16. Secondly, underneath, you can see my attempt to apply the np.polyfit to my graph, which when run, won't fit a characteristic but will output values. The value of p[0] is not perfect, so I believe something is wrong, but it is "close" to the desired output of 3. Is this a matter of just the wrong input or bad data?

```
def rk3(A,bvector,y0,interval,N):
    x0=interval[0]
    x_end=interval[1]
    x=np.linspace(x0,x_end,N+1)
    h=(x_end-x0)/N
    y=np.zeros((N+1,len(y0)))
    y[0, :] = y0
    for n in range(N):
        y_1=y[n,:]+h*(np.dot(A,y[n,:])+bvector(x[n]))
        y_2=(3/4)*y[n,:]+(1/4)*y_1+(1/4)*h*(np.dot(A,y_1)+bvector(x[n]+h))
        y[n+1,:]=(1/3)*y[n,:]+(2/3)*y_2+(2/3)*h*(np.dot(A,y_2)+bvector(x[n]+(1/2)*h))
    return x,y

err_vals = []
h_vals = []
for k in range(2,11): #for the range of N=40k, where k=1,...,10
    N=40*k
    x, y = rk3(A,bvector,y0,[0,0.1],N)
    yc = y[-1,:]
    h = (x[-1]-x[0])/N 
    h_vals.append(h)
    yvals.append(yc)
    yn = y[:,1]
    abs_err = np.zeros(N) 
    print("The value of y at k=",k," is ",yc)
for j in range(1,N):
    y_exact=np.array([np.exp(-1000*x[j]), (1000/999)*(np.exp(-x[j])-np.exp(-1000*x[j]))])
    y_exact_2 = y_exact[1]
    abs_err[j] = np.abs((y[j, 1] - y_exact_2)/y_exact_2)
Error = h*np.sum(abs_err[j])
err_vals.append(Error)

p = np.polyfit(np.log(h_vals), np.log(err_vals), 1)
pyplot.loglog(h_vals,err_vals,"kx")
pyplot.xlabel("h")
pyplot.ylabel("Error")
pyplot.loglog(h,np.exp(p[1])*h**(p[0]), 'r--')
print("Best fit line slope ",format(p[0]))
```

Comment: With `x` and `y` not given in your example, your problem is not reproducible. But given your found step size, perhaps your actual input values are also very small? In which case, you may run into floating point rounding errors. Normalize your input values to around 1 first before fitting.

Comment: @00 : The full description of the task can be found in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1532838/115115 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3417548/115115.

Comment: Short answer: The problem is stiff, explicitly constructed as such in the task description. It is to be expected that the linear segment of slope 3 is either very short or completely missing in the loglog plot of stepsize versus error.

Comment: Without actual output and expected output, and the lack of various input values (`h_vals`, `h`, `x`, `y`), this question is very hard to answer.

Comment: okay, I have updated to show the entire code for this section

Comment: I guess the two lines `Error = h*np.sum(abs_err[j])` and `err_vals.append(Error)` should be inside the for loop?

Comment: What are `A`, `bvector` and `y0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My evolution of your code below gives a completely straight line with slope close to 3 for the integration over the interval [0,0.01].

[image]

For the given interval [0,0.1] the slope value is about 1/3 larger. The error profiles, that is, the absolute error divided by the expected global error power of the step size, gives a converging pattern, confirming the convergence of order 3 of the method.

[image]

The error bound `2e7*h^3` is rather large, showing why the combination of problem and method can become very problematic for larger step sizes.

The error is computed via the L1 norms of the function difference and exact solution,

```
Error = sum(abs((y-y_exact(x))[:,1]))/sum(abs(y[:,1]))
```

giving a mathematically sound quantity. The summation of the local relative errors can lead to distortions of the total error where the exact solution has a root or small values. But still, even using your computation method of integrating the local relative error leaving out the first data point which is zero,

```
Error = sum(abs((y[1:,1]/y_exact(x)[1:,1]-1)))*h
```

gives a similar linear plot, with the range shifted down to 1e-7..1e-9, the slope staying at 3.0293

> Note that if you want to use the list `h_vals` in a computation like the one to plot the fitted line, you have to convert in into a numpy array first.

```
h=np.asarray(h_vals)
```

---

**complete code**

```py
def rk3(A,bvector,y0,interval,N):
    """Solves an IVP y'=f(x, y(x)) on x \in [0, x_end] with y(0) = y0 using N points, using Runge-Kutta method."""    
    x=np.linspace(*interval,N+1)
    h=x[1]-x[0]
    y=np.zeros((N+1,len(y0)))
    y[0, :] = y0
    for n in range(N):
        y_1=y[n]+h*(np.dot(A,y[n])+bvector(x[n]))
        y_2=(3/4)*y[n,:]+(1/4)*y_1+(1/4)*h*(np.dot(A,y_1)+bvector(x[n]+h))
        y[n+1]=(1/3)*y[n]+(2/3)*y_2+(2/3)*h*(np.dot(A,y_2)+bvector(x[n]+0.5*h))
    return x,y

A = np.array([[-1000.0,0.0],[1000.0,-1.0]]);
bvector = lambda x: 0
y_exact = lambda x: np.array([np.exp(-1000*x), (1000/999)*(np.exp(-x)-np.exp(-1000*x))]).T
y0 = y_exact(0)

plt.figure(figsize=(6,3));
h_vals, y_vals, err_vals = [],[],[] 
for k in range(2,11): #for the range of N=40k, where k=1,...,10
    N=40*k
    x, y = rk3(A,bvector,y0,[0,0.01],N)
    yc = y[-1,:]
    h = x[1]-x[0]; 
    plt.plot(x,(y-y_exact(x))[:,1]/h**3)
    h_vals.append(h)
    y_vals.append(yc)
    yn = y[:,1]
    print("The value of y at k=",k," is ",yc)
    Error = sum(abs((y-y_exact(x))[:,1]))/sum(abs(y[:,1]))
    err_vals.append(Error)
plt.grid(); plt.show()

p = np.polyfit(np.log(h_vals), np.log(err_vals), 1)

plt.figure(figsize=(6,4))
plt.loglog(h_vals,err_vals,"kx")
h=np.asarray(h_vals)
plt.plot(h,np.exp(p[1])*h**(p[0]), '--r', lw=0.5)
plt.xlabel("h")
plt.ylabel("Error")
plt.grid(); plt.show()
print("Best fit line slope ",format(p[0]))
```

Comment: Because you would have to apply it to the sum in numerator and denominator equally. So I just left it cancelled out. Note that in the text in the sum of relative errors the factor `h` is multiplied, as there is no counter-weighting denominator.